# ¿Como copiar un archivo desde un servidor linux a mi pc local?

Tags: ubuntu-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito copiar el archivo backup.sql a mi pc local. tengo accesso a la consola que proporciona digitalocean como administrador.
entiendo que se puede usar el comando ***...# scp backup.sql [DESTINO]*** pero, como defino el destino si deseo obtener el archivo en mi pc local(windowds).

Comment: Tienes que invertir los parámetros en el scp. Es decir, sería algo como: scp `user@server.tld:/ruta_archivo/backup.sql .` el . Final hace referencia a tu directorio actual, donde ejecutas el scp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion es usar la consola de tu sistema operativo en windows (cmd o git bash) en linux (terminal). El problema era que estaba usando la consola terminal de digitalocean pero tambien probe con la consola terminal de putty y no veia la solución. Luego probe en mi gitbash de windowds el comando scp(no funcionaba en windows) luego probe el comando pscp y si lo tenia puesto que ya habia instalado putty, entonces hice la primera prueba de conexion con el comando: [documentacion](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html)

- PASO 1

  pscp -ls root@miIPremoto:directorioRemoto

ahi te pedira la contraseña y te lista los archivos.

- PASO 2

*backup.sql* es mi archivo en la maquina remota y *d:/digitalocean* es mi ruta destino en mi pc windows y ejecuto el siguiente comando en mi gitbash

```
pscp -scp usuarioRemoto@miIPremota:backup.sql d:/directorioPClocal
```

no vean el password :)

[image: Solucion descargar archivos]

Answer (score 1):

Con scp das origen y destino. Si ejecutas en tu máquina local, el origen es remoto:

```
scp usuario@ip.de.origen:/carpeta/remota/archivo.txt /home/usuario/carpeta/destino/
```

Si ejecutas en la máquina remota, el destino es tu máquina y tienes que tener una forma de identificarla desde el origen:

```
scp /home/usuario/carpeta/origen/archivo.txt tu_usuario@ip.pc.local:/carpeta/remota/
```

Si desde ese servidor no sabes cómo identificar tu máquina local, siempre puedes correr scp desde tu máquina local con el origen remoto :)

Comment: Es verdad, desde  la consola del servidor remoto no se puede definir mi PC local. Encontré la solución con el comando pscp  en windows

Comment: @JuanCarlosAjahuanaQuispe publícala como respuesta. Puedes recibir votos positivos y la puedes marcar como aceptada (creo que 12 horas después de publicarla). Y lo mejor, le ayudas a otros en el futuro :)  PD. A la próxima, tienes que aclarar que el pc local es windows! :{